# Exporting to Excel rich text box

Tags: c#, richtextbox, export-to-excel

In c#, Rich text content are saved to database in below format
< b>Hello< /b>.

I need to export this to MS Excel sheet as **Hello** (with bold letters)

When ever i try to export the content in excel , its not showing in rich text. Kindly help me . Thanks,

```
           var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();               
            var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("");     
            int rowNumber = 1;              

            NPOI.SS.UserModel.IFont font = workbook.CreateFont();
            font.Boldweight = (short)(NPOI.SS.UserModel.FontBoldWeight.BOLD);
            font.FontHeight = 210;
            font.FontName = "Calibri";

            NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICellStyle headerCell = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
            headerCell.FillBackgroundColor = NPOI.SS.UserModel.IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.Index;
            headerCell.FillForegroundColor = NPOI.SS.UserModel.IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.Index;
            headerCell.FillPattern = NPOI.SS.UserModel.FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND;
            headerCell.VerticalAlignment = NPOI.SS.UserModel.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
            headerCell.WrapText = true;
            headerCell.SetFont(font);
            headerCell.BorderBottom = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.THIN;
            headerCell.BorderLeft = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.THIN;
            headerCell.BorderRight = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.THIN;
            headerCell.BorderTop = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.THIN;
            NPOI.SS.UserModel.IFont fontShort = workbook.CreateFont();
            fontShort.Boldweight = (short)(NPOI.SS.UserModel.FontBoldWeight.NORMAL);
            fontShort.FontName = "Calibri";

            NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICellStyle normalCell = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
            normalCell.FillBackgroundColor = 50;
            normalCell.VerticalAlignment = NPOI.SS.UserModel.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
            normalCell.WrapText = true;
            normalCell.SetFont(fontShort);
            normalCell.BorderBottom = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.THIN;
            normalCell.BorderLeft = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.THIN;
            normalCell.BorderRight = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.THIN;
            normalCell.BorderTop = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.THIN;

            NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICellStyle emptyCell = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
            emptyCell.SetFont(font);
            emptyCell.BorderBottom = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.NONE;
            emptyCell.BorderLeft = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.NONE;
            emptyCell.BorderRight = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.NONE;
            emptyCell.BorderTop = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.NONE;
    var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);
    var output ="<b>HelloWorld</b>"                          
            var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber++);
            row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(output); 
            row.Cells[0].CellStyle = normalCell;
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: 'In c#, Rich text content are saved to database in below format' => what database, how are you 'saving' it to the database

Comment: In database its saved as < strong>Hello World < /strong>. Where here strong refers as Bold. In UI ,i am able to see it as Hello World in bold letters. But while exporting i am not able to. The thing is I might have in my rich text box, bold italics,underline, bullets, color etc.

Comment: MS SQL, it of datatype nvarchar. So it will be saved in database as <strong> Hello World</strong>

Comment: This is my rich text content 
<p>
<strong>Hi This </strong><
span style="text-decoration: underline;">is a sample
</span> 
exampe
<span style="text-decoration: underline;"> on how thing will be working </span>
<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">from here</span> 
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">on in the new project</span>
<strong>.</strong></p>  
<ul>  
 <li>Yes</li>  
 <li>No</li>  
 <li>MayBe</li>  
 <li>w<em>ork</em>s.</li>  
 <li>Thanks</li>  
</ul>